# Kinesis shard read limit is 2 mib so how is it possible that a get record call can get upto 10mib

Tags: amazon-kinesis

I am referring to this [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/service-sizes-and-limits.html) where it says "Each shard can support up to a maximum total data read rate of 2 MiB per second via GetRecords. If a call to GetRecords returns 10 MiB, subsequent calls made within the next 5 seconds throw an exception."
I am trying to understand how is it possible that a getRecords call can get(10Mib) which is more than shard limit of 2mib? Will not the shard stop/throw erro after it reached the 2 mib limit?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence looks contradictory to itself. They should rephrase it.

You should take into account the first two statements from the document to understand the context.

Excerpts from mentioned document,

> GetRecords can retrieve up to 10 MiB of data per call from a single
>   shard, and up to 10,000 records per call. Each call to GetRecords is
>   counted as one read transaction.
>
> Each shard can support up to five read transactions per second. Each
>   read transaction can provide up to 10,000 records with an upper limit
>   of 10 MiB per transaction.
>
> Each shard can support up to a maximum total data read rate of 2 MiB
>   per second via GetRecords. If a call to GetRecords returns 10 MiB,
>   subsequent calls made within the next 5 seconds throw an exception.

According to my experience with Kinesis, What they actually mean is, each shard have 2 MiB per second read rate limit for GetRecords call and this rate limit is calculated over more than one second window at the start of GetRecords call.

I am not sure about Kinesis internal implementation, but I know [internals of Kafka](https://thehoard.blog/how-kafkas-storage-internals-work-3a29b02e026). In Kafka, partitions(same as shards in Kinesis) are further divided into segments which are basically log files. So, each message is stored as an entry in a log file.

I suspect they have implemented GetRecords server side API in following way,

pythonish pseudo code:

```
current_timestamp = datetime.now
seconds_diff = (LAST_SUCCESSFUL_CALL.timestamp - current_timestamp).total_seconds()
if LAST_SUCCESSFUL_CALL.data_size > (seconds_diff * 2 Mib):
  LAST_SUCCESSFUL_CALL.data_size = LAST_SUCCESSFUL_CALL.data_size - (seconds_diff * 2 Mib)
  throw Error
else
  records = data_store.find_next_records_from_segments(10 MiB)
  # Here, implementation does not limit the records because sequential disk reading is always faster. 
  # So, It will be better to get as much records it has with some upper cap of 10 MiB or till the end of segment. 
  LAST_SUCCESSFUL_CALL.data_size = records.data_size
  LAST_SUCCESSFUL_CALL.timestamp = current_timestamp
  return records
```

By spreading the rate limit check across previous call, they are making their implementation simpler.

It is also best for stream processing applications where consumer can catch up with records rapidly.

For example, suppose following events take place

```
T1 -> Ingest 1 MiB in shard, Consumer is busy on processing fetched data, Pending data = 1 MiB
T2 -> Ingest 1 MiB in shard, Consumer is busy on processing fetched data, Pending data = 2 MiB
T3 -> Ingest 1 MiB in shard, Consumer is busy on processing fetched data, Pending data = 3 MiB
T4 -> Ingest 1 MiB in shard, Consumer is busy on processing fetched data, Pending data = 4 MiB
T5 -> Ingest 1 MiB in shard, Consumer is busy on processing fetched data, Pending data = 5 MiB
T6 -> Ingest 1 MiB in shard, Consumer becomes idle and does GetRecords, gets 5 MiB data, Pending data = 1 MiB
T7 -> No new data ingestion, Consumer is busy on processing fetched data 
T8 -> No new data ingestion, Consumer is busy on processing fetched data 
T9 -> Consumer becomes Idle and does GetRecords, gets 1 MiB data. Pending data = 0 MiB
```

So T7 to T8, 2 seconds gets used by consumer to fully process 5 MiB of data, instead of separately making GetRecords for 2 MiB of data each. Here we are saving network calls and disk seeks.

In conclusion,

> Will not the shard stop/throw erro after it reached the 2 mib limit?

No, It will not. But GetRecords made in subsequent seconds will throw error. But mostly your consumer will spend those subsequent seconds processing that 10 MiB data which you received on first GetRecords call, instead of querying for new data. So, you will not have to worry about it that much.

Comment: Great explaination , you cleared my doubt ,, thanks much